# How to change the styling of a selected row in MUI5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styling

I am fairly new to MaterialUI and I'm using V5. I have seen the code samples for this on v4 but not sure how to do the same on mui5. I have a data grid and I want to change the background color + font colour when selected. How do I do this?

My current table:
[image]

Comment: Can you share some of your code that's relevant here?

Comment: I am using the data grid component with default settings. I actually got the required code, attaching it in reply below!

Answer (score 7):

Update: Got a sandbox code demo to my query. This should be good
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-dijkstra-zc2rhs?file=/src/Demo.tsx

Edit: Attaching the code below

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    //@ts-ignore - this isn't in the TS because DataGird is not exported from `@mui/material`
    MuiDataGrid: {
      styleOverrides: {
        row: {
          "&.Mui-selected": {
            backgroundColor: "rebeccapurple",
            color: "yellow",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "purple"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant answering code in the answer instead of in the link?

Comment: Yeah sure, will attach it

Answer (score 0):

@Rick45888, now you can use the following for typescript support in pro components-

```
import type {} from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro/themeAugmentation";
```

Comment: No need to add ts-ignore, also I could add comment on Rick's answer because I do not have reputation yet! Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).